# Phonegap android twitter in android 4.1

Tags: android, cordova, twitter, twitter-oauth, phonegap-plugins

In my android application, I am using tweet feature and I am using as explained in http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1. It is not working in version 4.0.3 android device. The childbrowser is not getting opened. I am using cordova-2.0.0 but still it's not working. May I know the problem?

Regards
Ashwini

Answer (score 0):

For twitter login page to get opened, your device must be set to current date and time properly otherwise, it doesn't open. Because, we need to pass current timestaps to get request_token. Check once.